# Smoothly piecing together two flows

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

i have the following problem: I have a compact codimension 1 submanifold $M\subset N$, seperating $N$ into two components, and two regular vector fields, say $X$ and $Y$, defined on a neighbourhood of $M$ with corresponding flows $\phi_X$ and $\phi_Y$, whose integral curves cross $M$ transversally (and go in the same direction). Because $M$ is compact, there is an $\varepsilon>0$ such that the flows are defined on $[-\varepsilon,\varepsilon]\times M$. I now want to construct a smooth map $H:[-\varepsilon,\varepsilon]\times M\to N$ (actually an embedding), with the property

$H(t,x)=\begin{cases}\phi_X(t,x), t\leq -\frac{\varepsilon}{2} \\ \phi_Y(t,x), t\geq \frac{\varepsilon}{2}\end{cases}$

I guess one needs some sort of bump function, but i am struggeling to work out the details. Any help is highly appreciated :)

Comment: Can you write this down with bump functions when $N=\Bbb R^n$?

Comment: I have found one construction, basically slowing down and accelerate the curves at the points, where smoothness is lost (in case of the map $H$ this would be for time $t=0$, if one defines $H$ to be $\phi_X$ for $t\leq 0$ and $\phi_Y$ for $t\geq 0$). But i dont want to lose the regularity of the curves...